# mysql query fetch latest 5 records from each column

Tags: php, mysql

I am new to Php and Mysql. I have a table called ut_posts having multiple columns.I want to query latest 5 records from each column based on the column status as 1. Below is my query to fetch records. But it seems to be not working.

```
SELECT * FROM( 
SELECT * FROM ut_posts WHERE political_news = 1 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,5
UNION ALL 
SELECT * FROM ut_posts WHERE cinema_news= 1 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,5
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM ut_posts WHERE latest_videos = 1 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,5 
)  a
```

But I am getting below error

```
Error Code: 1221
Incorrect usage of UNION and ORDER BY
My requirement is I want to display latest 5 records from each column.
```

How can I achieve this, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM
( SELECT * FROM ut_posts WHERE political_news = 1 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,5) t1 
UNION
SELECT * FROM(SELECT * FROM ut_posts WHERE cinema_news= 1 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,5) t2 
UNION
SELECT * FROM( SELECT * FROM ut_posts WHERE latest_videos = 1 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,5 ) t3
```

Comment: This  query is working like @lad2025 but I am getting duplicate records . For example I am having where cinema_news = 1 6 records. But with the above query I am getting 9 records.

Answer (score 3):

You could use:

```
(SELECT * FROM ut_posts WHERE political_news = 1 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,5)
UNION ALL 
(SELECT * FROM ut_posts WHERE cinema_news= 1 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,5)
UNION ALL
(SELECT * FROM ut_posts WHERE latest_videos = 1 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,5);
```

Comment: The above query is working but I am getting duplicate records . For example I am having where  cinema_news = 1  6 records. But with the above query I am getting 9 records.

Comment: The above query will also work like expected if you use union in place of union all.

Comment: Wasn't there originally a note to create a separate table for news? IMHO a good suggestion.